# Dont Send email for customers by email opencart 2.3.0.2 in admin

Tags: php, email, smtp, opencart, opencart2.3

i want to send email for customers email but show message successful but not send email for yahoo or gmail an other.
my opencart is `2.3.0.2`

**Secure SSL/TLS Settings (Recommended)**

```
Username:   sales@Max10.com
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    23.host.com
IMAP Port: 693 POP3 Port: 695
Outgoing Server:    23.host.com
SMTP Port: 512
```

IMAP, POP3, and SMTP require authentication.

**Non-SSL Settings (NOT Recommended)**

```
Username:   sales@Max10.com
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    mail.Max10.com
IMAP Port: 163 POP3 Port: 120
Outgoing Server:    mail.Max10.com
SMTP Port: 25
```

IMAP, POP3, and SMTP require authentication.

**and setting email in admin:**

Mail Tab

```
Mail Protocol
SMTP

Mail Parameters
-fsales@Max10.com or sales@Max10.com

SMTP Host 
mail.Max10.com

SMTP Username 
sales@Max10.com

SMTP Password 
mypass

SMTP Port 
25

SMTP Timeout 
5

New Order Alert Mail
yes
New Account Alert Mail
yes
Additional Alert E-Mails
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail Protocol
SMTP

Mail Parameters
null

SMTP Host 
23.host.com

SMTP Username 
sales@Max10.com

SMTP Password 
mypass

SMTP Port 
25

SMTP Timeout 
5

New Order Alert Mail
yes
New Account Alert Mail
yes
Additional Alert E-Mails
null

now :
set gmail account in tab Store.

Login to your account gmail, then at the link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps choose allow.

Comment: very well.ok:))