# couldn't send email in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am New to opencart.I have to send mail from contact page.I set the parameters in admin panel.

**Mail Protocol:** SMTP

**Mail Parameters:**-femailid@gmail.com

**SMTP Hostname:** smtp.gmail.com

**SMTP Username:** emailid@gmail.com

**SMTP Password:** Password

```
$email_to = "emailid@gmail.com";
$message = '';
$message .= 'Name:'.$_POST['name'];
$message .= 'Email'.$_POST['email'];
$message .= 'Phone'.$_POST['phone'];
$message .= 'Message'.$_POST['message'];
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');
$mail->setTo($email_to);
$mail->setFrom("emailid@gmail.com");
$mail->setSender("emailid@gmail.com");
$mail->setSubject("Contact");
$mail->setText($message);

$mail->send();
print_r($mail);
if(!$mail->send()){
echo "failed";
}else{
echo "success";
}
```

I dont understand why its not working. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: have you checked your log file for errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398017/dont-send-email-for-customers-by-email-opencart-2-3-0-2-in-admin